# how to find letters that don't occur in either string?

Tags: python

I need to write code that prints out all letters that don't appear in either of the two strings. So basically what I have does the opposite. Prints out all the letters that occur in both strings. Here is the code. I'm not sure how to change it.

```
s1 = input('Enter a string:\n')
s2 = input('Enter second string:\n')
s1 = set(s1)
s2 = set(s2)

def notInother(s1, s2):
    chars = []
    for char in (s1,s2):
        if char not in s2:
            if char not in s1:
                chars.append(char)
    print(chars)
```

Comment: `set(string.ascii_letters) - (s1 | s2)`

Comment: First you have to make a string of all possible characters `abcdef....`. Replace your expression (s1,s2) with that. Leave out the line making chars an empty list.

Comment: @Ozgur's solution is very elegant, but may be too good for your prof to believe :)

Comment: @roadrunner Yeah I was about to say that :). I need something simple and basic cause after all this is introduction to programming level :)

Comment: Mutating data structures and nested control flow are things that are difficult to reason about. The short functional solution is a lot simpler and more suitable for introductory-level programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm trying to write a really simple and basic answer.

---

A string containing the ASCII letters can be found in the `string` module

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
```

but of course you can write it directly in your code

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

You need two strings with the characters to be excluded

```
s1, s2 = 'abcdef', 'STUVWXYZ'
```

To solve your problem, you can build a list with the remaining letters using a *list comprehension* (I think that the code is self explanatory)

```
rl = [c for c in letters if c not in s1+s2]
```

Eventually, if you want to print the result of your code you can use the `.join()` method of the null string

```
print(''.join(rl))
```

that gives you

```
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you can merge two sets with `|`, then do `-` to get all letters from the alphabet with the ones in the string removed:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> set(ascii_letters) - (s1 | s2)
{'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', ...}
```

You might want to take a look at [set operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets#Set_Operations) to save yourself the mess of writing loops.

With for loop:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters

>>> def notInother(s1, s2):
...     chars = []
...     for char in ascii_letters:
...         if (char not in s1) and (char not in s2):
...             chars.append(char)
...     return chars
```

Comment: Really nice. Btw, there may be a need to use `string.ascii_lowercase` and `.lowercase on the inputs, if the result is not to distinguish be between caps and lowercase.

Comment: I would rather leave it up to OP as `A` and `a` might have to be treated differently in his program.

Comment: lower or uppercase isn't important in this case. The only thing is this is way to advance for my class and I'm sure my prof wouldn't allow me to submit it as it is now. Although I really like it :)

Comment: Instead of importing `ascii_letters` you can just write `ascii_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

Comment: Nice and clean solutions. I would like to point out that the second solution is definitely O(n^2), which is by no means a problem here. But, for personal reference, is the first solution also? Do you happen to know what the runtimes of the set operations are?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt good point. First solution takes linear time. You can check time complexity of all set operations from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Yeah I just modified a little bit and it works. Thanks alot @ozgur :)

Comment: Yes, but your example answer doesn't show Caps in the example set and it should

Comment: @ozgur Thanks for the info! It's really nice to see users who don't just go for TFGITW answers, but who actually provide the correct solution with alternatives, and links to more information. It's somewhat surprising (and a nice surprise, always) to find a user who will answer comments that aren't going to directly gain them rep.

Comment: I'm just envious :). Btw, I was the first to upvote it ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
import string
str1 = input('Enter a string:\n').lower()
str2 = input('Enter second string:\n').lower()
print(set(string.ascii_lowercase).difference(set((str1+str2).lower())))
```

Explanation:

- `set(string.ascii_lowercase)` is the set of lower-case alphabets
- `set((str1+str2).lower())` gives the concatenated set of string 1 & 2
  which are taken as inputs from use.
- `set1.difference(set2)` gives a set with elements in set1 but not in set2.

Comment: The solution is good, but an explanation would have been nice.

Comment: @Matthias explanation added.